# Windows x64 & "parenthesis in path" batch file problem

Tags: windows, path, batch-file, 64-bit, parentheses

Windows x64 versions contain folders named with parenthesis like "\Program Files (x86)" and this breaks a batch file I use. An example of a problem line:

for %%c in (%path%) do if exist "%%c\xyz.exe" set xyz=OK

i.e. when it reaches ")" in "(x86)" it puts out an error message and exits...

Any ideas on how to fix this?
This is a rather large batch file, and atm I don't have the time to rewrite it in a better language...

Many thanks :)

Comment: are you sure that you copied the very exact `FOR` instruction?

Comment: @PA yes, I can reproduce the error. I just can't think of a quick fix.

Comment: @PA Yes I only changed the executable name to xyz...

Comment: I don't reproduce the error in my system. Maybe a difference in language?

Comment: @PA I'm on a standard US English install, is that what you mean?

Comment: @PA To get the error you need to have a "Program Files (x86)\Something" entry in your PATH...

Comment: I did reproduce it. I was not using `PATH`, but `SET test` with double " around each part. That was working. Sorry for the misleading comment.

Comment: Cool, thanks for verifying it... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doesn't directly answer your question, but if you are trying to do what I thinking you are trying (which is make sure a file exists in the path) you can use something like the following in a batch file.

```
   @echo off
   for %%i in (xyz.exe) do set xyz=%%~$PATH:i

   if "%xyz%" == "" Goto NotFound

   Echo "Found"
   Goto TheEnd

:NotFound
   Echo "Not found"

:TheEnd
```

Comment: Works wonders... :)
And may I ask what all the %%~$: mean? Very cryptic... ;)

Comment: @stereo that's all documented in the usage of for. Type for /? at the console.

Answer (score 3):

Normally quoting should work, but in this case you want to iterate over all elements seperated by `;`.

But you can replace the `;` to a `" "` combination, so the brackets are quoted and you can iterate over the elements.

sample: `path=C:\temp;C:\windows;C:\Program Files (x86)`
The for-loop will search in
`"C:\temp" "C:\windows" "C:\Program Files (x86)"`

As code it looks like

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "searchPath=!path:;=" "!"
for %%c in ("!searchPath!") do (
    if exist "%%~c\xyz.exe" set xyz=OK
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the short names of the folder for this purpose. This is how you do it.

Open command promt in Windows.
Go to C drive (or the drive in which you have the Program Folder)
Type the following and

```
   c:\> dir /x  <Hit Enter>
```

This will return the short forms of all folders.

You will notice now that "\Program Files (x86)" will be represented as "PROGRA~2" (or an equivalent short name).
This is what I use to prevent any errors while creating Batch scripts.

For more options see here.
http://www.computerhope.com/dirhlp.htm

**Exlpanation for "dir /x"**
"This displays the short names generated for non-8dot3 file names. The format is that of /N with the short name inserted before the long name. If no short name is present, blanks are displayed in its place."

Comment: OP's PATH environment variable won't use short names.

Comment: Wouldn't such an approach cause him to have to iterate through all the folders as opposed to just the ones held by the "Path" environment variable?

Comment: This is a manual approach, defeating the purpose of the "for statement" and that of running batch files in general...